# axios interceptors can't access react context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-context

I have a context called auth and hook call useAxiosPrivate.
Inside the useAxiosPrivate hook's useEffect console log I can see AUTH context is logged in correctly. But when the error throws and interceptor runs, auth is null inside the interceptors. How can I fix this? What could go wrong here?

**Interceptors code.**

```js
import { InternalAxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { privateAxiosInstance } from "../utils/axios";
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";

export default function useAxiosPrivate() {
  
  const auth = useAuth();
  
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("AUTH",auth);
    const accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")!;
    
   
   
    const requestIntercept = privateAxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
      (config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
        if (config && !config?.headers?.Authorization && accessToken) {
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
        }
        return config;
      },
      (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    );

    const responseIntercept = privateAxiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
        return response;
      },
      async (error) => {
        const prevRequest = error?.config;

        // ACCESS TOKEN EXPIRED, RE-TRY WITH NEW ACCESS TOKEN
        
        console.log("AUTH INSIDE INTERCEPTORS",auth);

        if (error?.response?.status === 401 && !prevRequest?.sent) {
          console.log("1",error);
          prevRequest.sent = true;
          
          const token =  await auth?.refresh();
          

          prevRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
          return privateAxiosInstance(prevRequest);
        } else if (error?.response?.status === 401 && prevRequest?.sent) {
          console.log("2",error);
          return auth?.logout();
        } else {
          console.log("3",error);
          
          return Promise.reject(error);
        }
      }
    );

    return () => {
      privateAxiosInstance.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept);
      privateAxiosInstance.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept);
    };
    
  }, []);

  return privateAxiosInstance;
}
```

**Context's code**

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Auth, AuthProviderProps, AuthContextProps } from "../@types/auth";
import axiosInstance from "../utils/axios";
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import useAxiosPrivate from "../hooks/useAxiosPrivate";
const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextProps | null>(null);
AuthContext.displayName = "AuthContext";
export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};

export default function AuthProvider(props: AuthProviderProps) {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<Auth>({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    name: "",
    role: "",
    accessToken: "",
    refreshToken: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("AUTH CONTEXT");
    const accessToken = sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")!;
    const refreshToken = sessionStorage.getItem("refreshToken")!;

    if (accessToken && refreshToken) {

      setAuth((prev) => ({  isAuthenticated: true,
        name: "",
        role: "",
        accessToken,
        refreshToken, }));
    }

  }, []);

  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  const privateAxiosInstance = useAxiosPrivate();

  const login = (name: string, accessToken: string, refreshToken: string) => {
    setAuth({
      isAuthenticated: true,
      name,
      role: "",
      accessToken,
      refreshToken,
    });
    sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", accessToken);
    sessionStorage.setItem("refreshToken", refreshToken);

      privateAxiosInstance.get("/users/me",{
        headers: {
          authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken,
        },
      }).then((res) => {
      const { name } = res.data.user;
      setAuth((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: name }));
    });
  };

  const logout = () => {
    const refreshToken = sessionStorage.getItem("refreshToken")!;

    sessionStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
    sessionStorage.removeItem("refreshToken");

    axiosInstance.post(
      "/logout",
      {
        refreshToken: refreshToken,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: Date.now(),
        },
      }
    );

    enqueueSnackbar("sessiontimeout Logged out due to session expired", {
      variant: "error",
    });
    setAuth({
      isAuthenticated: false,
      name: "",
      role: "",
      accessToken: "",
      refreshToken: "",
    });
    window.location.href = "/";
  };

  const refresh = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("refreshing");
      if (!auth.refreshToken) {
        throw new Error("Refresh token not found!");
      }

      const { data } = await axiosInstance.post(
        "/accessToken",
        {
          refreshToken: auth.refreshToken,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: Date.now(),
          },
        }
      );

      sessionStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.accessToken);
      setAuth((prev) => ({ ...prev, accessToken: data.accessToken }));
        
      return data.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
      logout();
    }
  };

  const setName = (name: string) => {
   
    setAuth((prev) => ({ ...prev, name: name }));
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, login, logout, refresh, setName }}>
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try adding `auth` to the dependency array of the `useEffect` inside `useAxiosPrivate` to re-initialize interceptors with the updated `auth` variable